# Trigger won't return the proper user object in Realm/MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, realm, mongodb-atlas

With Realm sync of MongoDB, I'm trying to launch a trigger when a realm user is created to insert his newly created ID into my cluster.  Here's the javascript function I made that is being called by the trigger :

```
exports = async function createNewUserDocument({ user }) {

  const users = context.services
    .get("mongodb-atlas")
    .db("BD")
    .collection("patients");
    
  const query = { email: context.user.data.email };
  
  const update = {
    $set: {
      patientId: context.user.id
    }
  };
  
  // Return the updated document instead of the original document
  const options = { returnNewDocument: true };
  
  console.log(context.user.data.email);

  return users.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options)
    .then(updatedDocument => {
      if(updatedDocument) {
        console.log(`Successfully updated document: ${updatedDocument}.`)
      } else {
        console.log("No document matches the provided query.")
      }
      return updatedDocument
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(`Failed to find and update document: ${err}`))
};
```

When running from the embed editor, **while specifying the proper user manually**, it's working perfectly.  However, when launched by the trigger, it looks like the user is the system user and not the created user, because the error I get in the logs is the same I get when I run from the editor by specifying System user, which is *Failed to find and update document: FunctionError: cannot compare to undefined*.  This makes sense because the System user is not a user per se, so the context.user is undefined.

I find it weird since I specify in the function settings that it should be executed with the permissions of the user calling the function.  So my question is, is it possible to access the user.context of a user on his creation, and if so, how would I do it ?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was going on?  I'm running into something similar, only the document exists, the query is correct when ran through compass, but I still get the 'cannot compare to undefined'.  I don't think it's the user context since I'm using the exact same trigger for a similar scenario that works fine.